# Ruby on Rails: Data gather from blogsites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a very broad question, so please bear with me.

I wanted to create an app that gets data from another website, specifically medium.com. However, I don't think medium has an API.

Specifically, what I wanted to achieve is to search the medium.com of articles that has 500 or more likes, or perhaps one that has 50 or more responses (comments). I wanted to do it with ruby on 
How do you think I can do that? Please if you know how, point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: hmm, did you try searching for medium's api? https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend webscraping using the ruby gem called nokogiri.
It is a generic way of obtaining data that can be used for almost any website.

Take a look at these links to get started :-)
[Web Scraping with Ruby and Nokogiri for Beginners](https://www.distilled.net/resources/web-scraping-with-ruby-and-nokogiri-for-beginners/)
And a personal favourite
[Parsing HTML with Nokogiri](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/)

Comment: I would check on it. Thanks for guiding me!! Now I know where to start @orion

Comment: You are very welcome! It  might take a bit of time to get your head around it but persist with it, ask questions if you get stuck. It is totally worth it. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no API to get all POSTS, neither search them, see https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs/issues/48

Comment: yeah I guessed so too. That's why I wanted to do it manually via parsing of data, though I'm just a beginner on RoR. That's also why I asked what methods should I do to do it. Though thanks for confirming it! :)